# Dereferencing collection Hibernate

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, hql

I have HQL query

```
SELECT contact.countryCode, contact.firstName, contact.familyName, **contact.accounts.country**
FROM
Contact contact, IN (contact.accounts)accounts 
WHERE
contact.gender = ? OR accounts.country = ?
```

and  getting illegal attempt to dereference collection [contact0_.id.accounts] with element property reference [country].

Where, as you guess, "accounts" is a collection. What am i missing to be able to access this field from the contact object?

Thank you

Comment: What would your resultset look like?

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon: I would get the rows, and yes, I assume there would be duplication of Contact rows, because of multiple accounts. But is this possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already created an alias `accounts` for `contact.accounts`, and you should use it in `SELECT`:

```
SELECT contact.countryCode, contact.firstName, contact.familyName, accounts.country ...
```

Also I'm not sure aboutn NHibernate, but `JOIN` seems to be more widely used syntax for that construct:

```
SELECT contact.countryCode, contact.firstName, contact.familyName, accounts.country 
FROM Contact contact JOIN contact.accounts accounts
WHERE contact.gender = ? OR accounts.country = ?
```

Comment: Thanx for the response! Well i know that join would be the way to go, but this query is generated automatically, with query builder (user picks the fields (obtained with reflection) and as input to he query generator, the declared field names are sent ). There, aliases are build and reference hierarchy. So i can not make joins, since query builder does not know them. OK i will try now with this accounts alias. I hope i explained.(not sure)